# Access to key inside Dictionary get in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Is it possible to access the key inside of a *Dictionary get* in Swift ?

The main idea is:

In this code

```
var _dict:[String:String]  = [:]

var dict:[String:String] {
    
    //get the key
    
    return _dict

}

_dict = ["key 1":"Value 1","key 2":"Value 2"]

print(dict["key 1"])
```

Access the key to check if the value  exists, if it exists return the value if not generate the value for that key

Comment: I'm certain this is possible (it's the `subscript` function), but it's not clear the interface you're expecting. The example you've given here just return `"Value 1"`. What are you thinking about?

Comment: my ideia is validate if the return value is valid inside the get

Comment: And if it it isn't valid? And what is "valid" in this case? `nil` is a valid value to return. What are you expecting?

Comment: If the key existes,  returns the value if not generates the value for that key

Comment: What does "generates the value" mean? Is there some function that generates these values? Forget about Dictionary. Think about `func something(string: String) -> String`. How would you implement it? Dictionary is just syntactic sugar around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you know that `Dictionary` allows you to specify a default value in its subscript to avoid dealing with optional values. It works like so:

```
let dict = ["a": 1, "b": 2]
let c = dict["c", default: 3] 

print(c) // 3
```

but that doesn't change the dictionary - it's still only has `"a"` and `"b"` keys, which is the expected behavior.

I think what you're asking about is whether it's possible to mutate the dictionary with a default value. The answer is yes - you could create a subscript with a `mutating get`.

**But it's the wrong thing to do!**

You will effectively have a getter with side-effects, which is typically a bad practice.

In any case, this is how you could implement a subscript with a new parameter `setDefault`:

```
extension Dictionary {
   subscript(key: Key, setDefault defaultVal: @autoclosure () -> Value) -> Value {
      mutating get {
         if let val = self[key] { 
            return val 
         } else {
            let val = defaultVal()
            self[key] = val
            return val
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
// dict needs to be a var now
var dict = ["a": 1, "b": 2]
let c = dict["c", setDefault: 3]
```

Now, this will mutate `dict` and it will be `["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3]`